# Is a <form> valid over a <tr>?

Tags: html

Is the following valid HTML?  What I am wondering about specifically is the location of the `<form>` tag.

```
<table>
    <form>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="txt" type="text"></input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txt" type="text"></input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Comment: i feel illogical about putting form between the table this way. How about wrapping the WHOLE table with form? =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recomment using the w3c validator http://validator.w3.org/. And no its not valid :-)

Comment: i would like to give you 100 upvotes for this...most developers ignore this great type of validation :-(

Answer (score 8):

It's not valid. I'm guessing you want to remove the default padding of the form element. This is better done through CSS:

```
form {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

or

```
<form style="padding:0;margin:0;">
```

Your approach used to be very common to remove the default form padding (before CSS became popular). Now you should put the form tags outside the table. Preferrably you shouldn't even use a table here, but that's not the question, so I'll let it slide. ;)

Comment: Or he may have just wanted to use multiple forms across one table spanning to more than one row? He is probably better off using divs to accomplish that.

Comment: @Ivan - Javascript should be used for that, assigning values to a hidden form and submitting, since using multiple identical forms does not make sense, seeing as only one form can be submitted per page. He could assign an id to the row and use that to identify it.

Answer (score 3):

No this is not valid, `TABLE` can only contain `TBODY`, `THEAD`, `TFOOT`, `CAPTION`, `COL`, `COLGROUP`. If you are using `XHTML` then you can also put `tr` inside the `table`.

Comment: The only child elements a table element can have are caption, col, colgroup, tbody, thead, and tfoot. (XHTML adds tr elements to that list). th elements are unacceptable.

Comment: I misspeled TH, I fixed that and added all the other elements (had to check the docs). Since he didn't specify what version of HTML he is using, I have added TR to the lis also :)

Comment: Apparently, my 4 minute old vote is too old to be changed unless the question is edited ... which it has been. You're still misspelling "TFOOTER" though, and "TR" is never acceptable - since XHTML is case sensitive ;) (If you add "tr" then please mention the XHTML conditional too).

Answer (score 2):

No. see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TABLE

```
<!ELEMENT TABLE - -
 (CAPTION?, (COL*|COLGROUP*), THEAD?, TFOOT?, TBODY+)>
```

The `<form>` element can appear in all places where you can have `block` content. So `<form>` can go in `<body>`,`<blockquote>`,`<noscript>` (oddly enough also in `<map>`). Because `block` can also go in `flow`, it may also appear in `<div>`,`<ins>`,`<del>`,`<dd>`,`<li>`,`<td>`,`<th>`

Comment: Forms cannot appear in forms or buttons, they are explicitly excluded: `<!ELEMENT FORM - - (%block;|SCRIPT)+ -(FORM) -- interactive form -->` and `<!ELEMENT BUTTON - -
     (%flow;)* -(A|%formctrl;|FORM|FIELDSET)
     -- push button -->`

Answer (score -3):

It's not proper HTML, but it's sometimes done to lose the empty lines.