# Form being closed unexpectedly, input should be inside but is outside of form

Tags: forms, codeigniter

I created a form (below) to collect a single input.

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
    <?=form_open('','data-id="'.$product['product_id'].'"')?>
         <tr class="<?=$product['product_id']?>">
            <td>
                <?=$product['product_name'];?>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-xs-12">

                          <!--single input-->
                          <input type="text" class="typeahead clean form-control" data-id="<?=$product['product_id']?>" autocomplete="off" name="<?=$product['product_id']?>">
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                 <div class="text-center">

                      <!--submit button-->
                      <button type="submit" class="font-tiny capitalized no-underline btn btn-primary btn-sm"> <i class="fa fa-check font-medium"></i> Submit</button>
                 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
 <?php } ?>
```

The code looks ok above and when I view page source, but when I inspect element the form is closed right away.  Like this:

```
<form action="http://merchantfuse.localhost:8888/company/add/batch_pending" data-id="7" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"></form>
```

The form is not working properly, when I submit it, the value submitted is from another input located in the header.  Does anyone have any idea as to why this might be happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opening and closing table html tags (`<table>` `</table>`) need to be inside your form tags. It is not valid html to split a table with a form so the browser ends the form straight away, see [Is a form valid over a tr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984599/is-a-form-valid-over-a-tr)

This will give you:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Cell content</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, this is odd as I had done this before and it worked ok for me.  We just switched to bootstrap 3 and now it stopped working.  Taking the form outside of the table does fix the <form> problem, but it fundamentally changes what I'm trying to do on the page.  I'm probably going to switch to something that doesn't use tables.

Comment: I guess you were trying to use each row of the table for an individual product showing the product name, an input and the submit button. You can still use the form wrapped around the whole table but change each submit button to an input instead of a button and then give each submit input a name which incorporates the product id such as product[23]. This way, you can tell which submit button was clicked.

Alternatively, to keep separate forms for each item, you could use inline-blocks for layout instead of the table.